# EC2 linux any and all upstart jobs returning "unrecognised service"

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, upstart

Having a nightmare migrating some upstart jobs from Ubuntu to EC2 Linux (ElasticBeanstalk)

I am unable to get even the most basic task to work. I am using the script below which works perfectly on Ubuntu but returns the very unhelpful "unrecognised service" when I try to start it in EC2 Linux. I have read this is usually a syntax error but that doesnt follow if this is syntactically OK for Ubuntu. Any help massively appreciated, I just need any working example.

This is in /etc/init/test.conf created as root user.

Console:

```
# sudo service test start
# test: unrecognized service
```

/etc/init/test.conf:

```
description "test"

start on startup

script
  echo $(ping -c 1 serverfault.com) > /var/log/testjob.log
end script
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So for some reason initctl likes it and service doesnt...

```
sudo initctl start test
test start/running, process 8776
```

A bug in EC2 Linux me thinks. My example exactly conforms to the documentation but no biggy to switch to using initctl

If you like to check which services are running you also can do this:

```
sudo initctl list
```

And to verify where the log error read the file in `/var/log/messages`

Comment: Maybe I should have searched for this answer before spending a day trying to fix it myself, and then trying to install daemontools........

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the AWS Linux AMI instead of the Ubuntu one use:

```
start on started network
```

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion but no joy. Still giving me the "unrecognised service" error

Comment: what AMI are you using?

Comment: Latest EC2 Linux - whatever Amazon spin up with ElasticBeanstalk applications. Thanks for your help, found an answer posted below

Comment: Great, I'll keep that one in mind as well.

Comment: Further to your suggestion I think the elasticbeanstalk equivalent would be `start on started elastic-network-interfaces`

Comment: Your suggestion just saved me! I've been running with `start on startup` to no avail all day.

Answer (score 0):

With upstart, the syntax should be `sudo start test` and `sudo stop test`, rather than the "service" syntax used by the init.d system.

Comment: Amazon Linux uses an old version of Upstart, which does not recognise jobs in /etc/init